# How to mock the value of variable inside a class using Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

Test Class

```
Class TestClass{

    @Autowired
    AnyClass anyClass

    boolean testMethod() {
        boolean result = anyClass.method()
        if(result) {
            return !result
        }
        else {
            return !result
        }
    }
}
```

My Spock

```
class TestClassSpec implements Specification {

    AnyClass anyClass = Mock()
    TestClass testClass = new TestClass(anyClass: anyClass)

    def "check if opposite of result is returned"()  { 
        given: 
        anyClass.method >> {return true}

        when:
        boolean result = testClass.testMethod()

        then:
        result == false
    }
}
```

The result variable is always null when I try to debug. Is there anyway I can inject values into result variable without changing the original Test class?

Comment: Please make sure to share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you posted doesn't even fit together what is the relationship between `Test` and `TestClass` , how does `AnyClass` look like? And please use proper formatting, once you update your code.

Comment: There was a typo in test. The definition of anyClass and methods don't matter. The question I have is how to inject values into 'result' variable in 'testMethod'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment, your code does not make fit well but I would suggest you inject the variable this way:

```
  def "check if opposite of result is returned"() {
    when:
    boolean result = testClass.testMethod()

    then:
    anyClass.method() >> false

    and:
    result == false
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You code has several issues:

1. You need to `extend Specification` not `implement`
2. If you stub a method you need to include the `()`, e.g.,
   `anyClass.method >> {return true}` would try to mock a property, the correct invocation is `anyClass.method() >> true` this is the **main issue**
3. the `{ return true }` is redundant if you just want to return a fixed value
4. The if-else is entirely redundant

```
interface AnyClass {
    boolean method()
}

class TestClass{

    AnyClass anyClass

    boolean testMethod() {
        boolean result = anyClass.method()
        return !result        
    }
}

class TestClassSpec extends spock.lang.Specification {

    AnyClass anyClass = Mock()
    TestClass testClass = new TestClass(anyClass: anyClass)

    def "check if opposite of result is returned"()  { 
        given: 
        anyClass.method() >> true

        when:
        boolean result = testClass.testMethod()

        then:
        result == false
    }
}
```

Test it in the [Groovy Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=eJx1UUGOAiEQvPOK1pNe5gEmmhjPntYPsEzjEFmYQM-6m8n8XUTo0ezaJ6CrqrsK4wiDlgph734PVsYIo4BUn95blA6-kDrfrtZiEkLl_gkjZeQoMpKJshzEiwAl-LGIFO3ndsA4WIItsxueWKEBaQgOFgVaKrenf9b66FEB_hC6NkLsvbo0Vrpzc3832ihJxjt4t3za5JgoZTyLZhsV4PA6d1aVuWGN9UO7RQ1L1aG6gNHg-95HQwheV9MmFm_YLlM4MAJ7PptvdJv5_icd2O1gLMlQGHASjL12ifo-aHbSPH_NTKcXeqVtQUsbcU6dEfe6AY6xr7A)